# nginx proxy requests for a specific path

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to pass requests for a specific path to a different upstream server?

Here is my nginx site configuration:

```
upstream example.org {
    server 127.0.0.1:8070;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://example.org;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

Currently, requests to this site are redirected to a Node.js instance running on port 8070.

I would like requests to this site that have a path starting with ***/services*** to be redirected to another Node.js instance running on port 8080.

Is this possible?   And of course -- how so?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just add another **location** block:

```
upstream example.org {
    server 127.0.0.1:8070;
    keepalive 8;
}
upstream other.example.org {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.log;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://example.org;
    }

    location /services {
      proxy_pass http://other.example.org;
    }
 }
```

*Note:* I extracted all shared proxy directives into the **server** block so that they are not repeated in each **location** block. If they would differ between different locations, you would have to move them again into the **location** blocks...

Comment: This works except now the request to "http://other.example.org/" gets /services added to the end of it?

For example, I would like http://example.org/services/jobs to get forwarded to http://other.example.org/jobs  but right now it is get forwarded to http://other.example.org/services/jobs

Comment: @eat-sleep-code you can fix this by changing the *proxy_pass* directives to include a trailing slash, e.g. `proxy_pass http://other.example.org/;`. See the documentation for more info: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: @eat-sleep-code adding trailing slash wouldn't work unfortunately, can you suggest other workaround please?